# Are there any hack methods for accessing a parent property declared as internal?

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview

The problem is I have AspxGridView with Bands and Columns. I need to add Bands (class `GridViewBands`) with `ColRowSpan = 2`, but this property exists only in parent class - `GridViewColumn`. `GridViewColumn` has property `ColRowSpan`, but it is declared as "protected internal".
Also, I tried to access it during debug - it works! But in the code I got exception.

Please, let me know does any method exist to access and change this property?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It needs to use Reflection in this case. The code will be like this:<b

```
var gridViewColumnType = typeof(GridViewColumn);
var cellRowSpanProperty = gridViewColumnType.GetProperty("CellRowSpan", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
cellRowSpanProperty.SetValue(bandcolumn, 2);
```